# How to calculate Jaccard Similarity in R and why it does not work

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the Jaccard index on R, to test similarity among boolean data.
I tried with the library Jaccard, but if I do a simple test with

```
e=c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
f=c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
g= c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
h= c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
jaccard.test(e,f,method = "mca")
jaccard.test(g,h,method="mca")
```

I obtain as output

```
> jaccard.test(e,f,method = "mca")
$statistics
[1] 0.6666667

$pvalue
[1] NaN

$expectation
[1] 0.3333333

$accuracy
[1] 1

$error.type
[1] "average"

> jaccard.test(g,h,method="mca")
$statistics
[1] 0.5714286

$pvalue
[1] NaN

$expectation
[1] 0.4285714

$accuracy
[1] 1

$error.type
[1] "average"
```

Shouldn't I obtain $statistics=1 in both cases?

I also tried to built manually the function, as reported here https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/11/how-to-calculate-jaccard-similarity-in-r/
with

```
jaccard_similarity <- function(a, b) {
  intersection = length(intersect(a, b))
  union = length(a) + length(b) - intersection
  return (intersection/union)
}
```

but with the same above example I obtain

```
> jaccard_similarity(e,f)
[1] 0.2
> jaccard_similarity(g,h)
[1] 0.25
>
```

I do not understand, since in my understanding of Jaccard Similarity, I should also here obtain 1 in both cases.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to calculate the jaccard similarity is:

```r
sum(e & f) / sum(e | f)
##> [1] 1
```

If you want to calculate the jaccard similarity index between the rows of a logical (or 0/1) matrix, you can use:

```r
1 - dist(rbind(e,f), method = "binary")

##>   e
##> f 1
```

As for the `jaccard.test` function included in the jaccard package, if you look at the source code of `jaccard.test.exact`:

```r
function (x, y, px = NULL, py = NULL, verbose = TRUE) 
{
    if (length(x) != length(y)) 
        stop("Length mismatch")
    m <- length(x)
    null.p <- FALSE
    x <- as.logical(x)
    y <- as.logical(y)
    if (is.null(px) | is.null(py)) {
        px <- mean(x)
        py <- mean(y)
        null.p <- TRUE
    }
    degenerate <- FALSE
    expectation <- jaccard.ev(x, y, px = px, py = py)
    j.obs <- sum(x & y)/sum(x | y) - expectation
    if (px == 1 | py == 1 | sum(x) == length(x) | sum(y) == length(y)) {
        warning("One or both input vectors contain only 1's.")
        degenerate <- TRUE
    }
    if (px == 0 | py == 0 | sum(x) == 0 | sum(y) == 0) {
        warning("One or both input vectors contain only 0's")
        degenerate <- TRUE
    }
    if (degenerate) {
        return(list(statistics = 0, pvalue = 1, expectation = expectation))
    }
    if (!null.p) {
        pvalue <- jaccard_mca_rcpp_known_p(px, py, m, j.obs, 
            0)$pvalue
    }
    else {
        pvalue <- jaccard_mca_rcpp(px, py, m, j.obs, 0)$pvalue
    }
    return(list(statistics = j.obs, pvalue = pvalue, expectation = expectation))
}
```

You can see that the reported `statistics` is a jaccard similarity corrected by an "expectation" term as in `j.obs <- sum(x & y)/sum(x | y) - expectation`

Finally, my guess is that the `jaccard_similarity` function that you attached is supposed to work like this:

```r
jaccard_similarity(which(e == 1), which(f == 1))
#> [1] 1
```